# Fix precision issues when *displaying* floats in python

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, ipython, precision

I'm reading out a text file with some float numbers using `np.loadtxt` . This is what my numpy array looks like:

```
x = np.loadtxt(t2)
print(x)

array([[  1.00000000e+00,   6.61560000e-13],
       [  2.00000000e+00,   3.05350000e-13],
       [  3.00000000e+00,   6.22240000e-13],
       [  4.00000000e+00,   3.08850000e-13],
       [  5.00000000e+00,   1.11170000e-10],
       [  6.00000000e+00,   3.82440000e-11],
       [  7.00000000e+00,   5.39160000e-11],
       [  8.00000000e+00,   1.75910000e-11],
       [  9.00000000e+00,   2.27330000e-10]])
```

I separate out the first column from the second by doing this:

```
idx, coeffs = zip(*x)
```

Now, I want to create a mapping of id : coeff, something like this:

```
mapping = dict(zip(map(int, idx), coeffs))
print(mapping)

{1: 6.6155999999999996e-13,
 2: 3.0535000000000001e-13,
 3: 6.2223999999999998e-13,
 4: 3.0884999999999999e-13,
 5: 1.1117e-10,
 6: 3.8243999999999997e-11,
 7: 5.3915999999999998e-11,
 8: 1.7591e-11,
 9: 2.2733e-10}
```

As you can see, precision errors have been introduced. For example, `6.61560000e-13` became `6.6155999999999996e-13`.

This is what I would like, preferrably:

```
{1: 6.61560000e-13,
 2: 3.05350000e-13,
 3: 6.22240000e-13,
 4: 3.08850000e-13,
 ...
 }
```

How can I do this? I am working on IPython3, if that helps.

Comment: Eager downvoter, can you explain what you don't like about this post?

Comment: nmdv. Downvoting questions are cheap... back on topic, are you using `float32` when loading your array? because native python uses `double`

Comment: note that you don't have the rounding issue if x is just a list of lists (python)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No. I just allow numpy to detect the dtype automatically.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh... your comment has given me a great idea!

Comment: No precision errors have actually occurred.  You're seeing the limitations of representing a number with a bit pattern, and how the value appears on screen depends on the formatting of the printed value. `format(6.6156000000000000e-13,".16e")` produces '6.6155999999999996e-13'.  (Tested with Python 3.6).  That's as close as can be to 6.6156e-13, which cannot be represented exactly.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Yes. I understand the limitations of fp representation. My question was pertaining to how to get it to display as numpy does it (figured out how to as well).

Comment: OK, not to beat this point to death, but I'm curious now: how can the two instances of `mapping` produce two different printouts, unless their values are actually different?  And if 6.6156e-13 can't be represented exactly, how does the printed value get rounded so nicely to 4 decimal places in the second case but not in the first one? The default formatting is, in fact, "6.6156e-13" and in order to get the longer form I had to use the format function.  Can you explain what's going on?

Comment: @PaulCornelius: The key point to understand is that the `numpy.float64` type and the Python `float` type have different `__repr__` algorithms, so the exact same value can get displayed in two different ways. To see this, compare the `repr` of `np.float64(1.1)` with the `repr` of  `1.1`. The actual values stored are identical in both cases, but the reprs are different. Python uses David Gay's algorithm, while NumPy uses "compute 17 significant digits then truncate trailing zeros". @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution works because `tolist` also converts NumPy floats to Python floats.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson Very interesting. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jean-François Fabre's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688226/fix-precision-issues-when-displaying-floats-in-python?noredirect=1#comment78334374_45688226) gave me an idea, and I tried it out. Taking into consideration Alexander's suggestion to use a dict comprehension, this worked for me:

```
x = np.loadtxt(t2)
mapping = {int(k) : v for k, v in x.tolist()}

print (mapping)
```

Output:

```
{1: 6.6156e-13,
 2: 3.0535e-13,
 3: 6.2224e-13,
 4: 3.0885e-13,
 5: 1.1117e-10,
 6: 3.8244e-11,
 7: 5.3916e-11,
 8: 1.7591e-11,
 9: 2.2733e-10}
```

The reason this works is because `x` is of type `np.float64`. Calling `.tolist()` converts `x` to a list of lists, where each element is of type `double.` `np.float64` and `double` have different `__repr__` implementations. The `double` uses the [David Gay Algorithm](http://www.ampl.com/REFS/abstracts.html#rounding) to correctly represent these floats, while numpy has a much simpler implementation (mere truncation).

Comment: It may be worth explaining _why_ this works: namely, that the `tolist` method converts NumPy `float64` instances into regular Python `float`s, and the two types have different `repr`s.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes. I was aware of the Gay algorithm but did not realise numpy did not implement it. Thank you for your comment. I've added that bit.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the downvote.

After entering your data, you have already 'lost precision':

```
x = np.array([[  1.00000000e+00,   6.61560000e-13],
              [  2.00000000e+00,   3.05350000e-13],
              [  3.00000000e+00,   6.22240000e-13],
              [  4.00000000e+00,   3.08850000e-13],
              [  5.00000000e+00,   1.11170000e-10],
              [  6.00000000e+00,   3.82440000e-11],
              [  7.00000000e+00,   5.39160000e-11],
              [  8.00000000e+00,   1.75910000e-11],
              [  9.00000000e+00,   2.27330000e-10]])

>>> x[0, 1]
6.6155999999999996e-13
```

Perhaps a simple dict comprehension may be easier:

```
>>> {int(k): v for k, v in x}
{1: 6.6155999999999996e-13,
 2: 3.0535000000000001e-13,
 3: 6.2223999999999998e-13,
 4: 3.0884999999999999e-13,
 5: 1.1117e-10,
 6: 3.8243999999999997e-11,
 7: 5.3915999999999998e-11,
 8: 1.7591e-11,
 9: 2.2733e-10}
```

Comment: So it all comes back to the Gay algorithm for displaying floats. There is no way to fix this, correct?

Comment: I figured out a way, using `.tolist()`. Take a look at my answer!

Comment: That seems to have done the trick.  Not sure what benefit `dtype=np.float64` adds?

Comment: Lol... you're right. Was a remnant of some earlier attempts, but it seems to work without.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your method itself, you can cast your input (float) array to an `int` array and then construct dictionary after `zip`ing it.

```
In [44]: dict(zip(np.asarray(x[:,0], dtype=int).tolist(), x[:,1].tolist()))
Out[44]: 
{1: 6.6156e-13,
 2: 3.0535e-13,
 3: 6.2224e-13,
 4: 3.0885e-13,
 5: 1.1117e-10,
 6: 3.8244e-11,
 7: 5.3916e-11,
 8: 1.7591e-11,
 9: 2.2733e-10}
```

P.S. Using Python 3.6.1 in `IPython 6.1.0`