# Difference of precision/display between numpy.tolist() and list()

Tags: python, numpy, floating-accuracy

This is kind of a follow up to [coldspeed's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688226/fix-precision-issues-when-displaying-floats-in-python).

(And this is not a duplicate of [is floating point math broken ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?s=1%7C29.4652) BTW)

I'm converting a list of lists to a numpy array, and then trying to convert it back to a python list of lists.

```
import numpy as np

x = [[  1.00000000e+00,   6.61560000e-13],
       [  2.00000000e+00,   3.05350000e-13],
       [  3.00000000e+00,   6.22240000e-13],
       [  4.00000000e+00,   3.08850000e-13],
       [  5.00000000e+00,   1.11170000e-10],
       [  6.00000000e+00,   3.82440000e-11],
       [  7.00000000e+00,   5.39160000e-11],
       [  8.00000000e+00,   1.75910000e-11],
       [  9.00000000e+00,   2.27330000e-10]]

x=np.array(x,np.float)
print([y.tolist() for y in x])
print([list(y) for y in x])
```

Result:

```
[[1.0, 6.6156e-13], [2.0, 3.0535e-13], [3.0, 6.2224e-13], [4.0, 3.0885e-13], [5.0, 1.1117e-10], [6.0, 3.8244e-11], [7.0, 5.3916e-11], [8.0, 1.7591e-11], [9.0, 2.2733e-10]]
[[1.0, 6.6155999999999996e-13], [2.0, 3.0535000000000001e-13], [3.0, 6.2223999999999998e-13], [4.0, 3.0884999999999999e-13], [5.0, 1.1117e-10], [6.0, 3.8243999999999997e-11], [7.0, 5.3915999999999998e-11], [8.0, 1.7591e-11], [9.0, 2.2733e-10]]
```

Note that trying to match python native types also fails (same behavior):

```
x=np.array(x,dtype=float)
```

So converting the lists back to normal python lists using `numpy.tolist` preserves values, whereas forcing iteration by calling `list` on them introduces rounding errors.

Fun fact:

- `str([y.tolist() for y in x])==str([list(y) for y in x])` yields `False` (as expected, different printouts)
- `[y.tolist() for y in x]==[list(y) for y in x]` yields `True` (what the hell??)

Any thoughts? (using python 3.4 64 bits windows)

Comment: Equality testing at least recognises that the values are the same, even if their representation is muddy. What Python version is this on?

Comment: Looks like representation rather than precision to me

Comment: @JRichardSnape agreed but both `y.tolist()` and `list(y)` have the same type so they should be represented the exact same way

Comment: @MartijnPieters edited to show python 3.4 64

Comment: Fair point, you can check the lists themselves, they are exactly the same.  Musing on why the representation would be different.  BTW - repros on 2.7 as well (I checked as I usually do with these)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I was able to repro on OS X with 3.6.2 as well.

Comment: `list` iterates on the first dimension of the array (try `list(x)`).  `tolist` iterates through all dimensions, returning a (nested) list of Python objects.  Since `for y in x;` is just as good as `for y in list(x):`, we rarely need to use `list`.  `tolist` is much more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that the two methods produce different types that have different string representations even when holding the same value. Calling `np.tolist` converts the elements of the array to `float` data type while calling `list` is not changing the data type resulting in `numpy.float64`s:

```
import numpy as np

x = [[  1.00000000e+00,   6.61560000e-13],
       [  2.00000000e+00,   3.05350000e-13],
       [  3.00000000e+00,   6.22240000e-13],
       [  4.00000000e+00,   3.08850000e-13],
       [  5.00000000e+00,   1.11170000e-10],
       [  6.00000000e+00,   3.82440000e-11],
       [  7.00000000e+00,   5.39160000e-11],
       [  8.00000000e+00,   1.75910000e-11],
       [  9.00000000e+00,   2.27330000e-10]]

x=np.array(x,np.float)

print(type(x[0].tolist()[0]))     # `float`
print(type(list(x[0])[0]))        # `numpy.float64`
```

As those have different string representations (`float` getting rounded, while `numpy.float64` printing the full precision), different results are printed and the comparison of `str([y.tolist() for y in x])==str([list(y) for y in x])` fails, while the value wise comparison passes.

Comment: good. Any way to store the data in `numpy` array exactly like a python array?

Comment: agreed but doing that changes nothing.

Comment: Oh, yes I just realized that.

Comment: My *guess* is that `tolist()` does this deliberately in case you are passing the produced list to code that cannot be guaranteed to be aware of numpy types.  Not sure whether that's a good idea.  Nice work @jotasi.

Comment: Yup - here we are - "Data items are converted to the nearest compatible Python type." https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/75545583a89647b810862076ae385a6c396e3eb0/numpy/ma/core.py#L5761

Comment: Thanks @JRichardSnape. That seems to be the logical explanation.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Btw, it works if you use `object` as `dtype` of the array. Then you always get the rounded string conversion.